# Cancel out the effect of # hash symbol in text formatting creating headings

Tags: support, markdown

I don't understand how to properly format this particular thing (in block characters)

---

Just to fool around with script making, I made one that (I believe?) should open a terminal at startup:

#!/bin/bash
  #start terminal at startup
  #/usr/bin/gnome-terminal

---

The bit with the `#` (hash, pound or octothorpe symbol) causes the three lines to conform to one line, after I indented properly for block characters.

Without indents, I get this:

---

## !/bin/bash

## start terminal at startup

## /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

---

How would I use block characters in the presence of the hash or pound sign?

Comment: What do you mean by "block characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer is to create a "code block" by indenting every line
by ***four*** spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
#start terminal at startup
#/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

There are several ways to do this:

- Manually type four spaces in front of every line.
- Select your code, and then either

  - type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or
  - click on the `{}` button above the edit window.

You can also get partial lines in code mode by surrounding them with backticks
(`` ` ``...`` ` ``); e.g.,

`#!/bin/bash`

Or, to start a line with `#` without going into gray monospace mode,
just type a backslash (`\`) before it:

#start terminal at startup

Incidentally, this applies to

- Starting a line with `-` when the previous line is not blank.
- Starting a line with `- something`
  or `* something` when the previous line is blank.
- Starting a line with `---`, `___` or `***` when the previous line is blank.
- Using pairs of `*` or `_` characters
  as themselves: **this text is not bold**.

Comment: I realize that this answer overlaps with [Adam's](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/284309/300663#284310), but I submit that mine is more coherent and complete.

Answer (score 6):

Code blocks are the way to go here:

> Just to fool around with script making, I made one that (I believe?) should open a terminal at startup:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash #start terminal at startup #/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
> ```

You could also escape the # with a backslash:

> #!bin/bash

See [formatting help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more info.

Comment: I recommend using code formatting so that you can find the symbols [by searching](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675).

Comment: I'm sure you understand this stuff — so, when the OP asks how to present a three-line script, why do you demonstrate how to do it all on one line?

Comment: @PeregrineRook I just copy-pasted what they had since it's still a representative example of formatting.

Comment: the backlash worked but it stays...